# A simple Fetchmail use

Tags: email

I'm trying to backup my e-mail inbox using `Fetchmail`. So after installing the package, I created a `.fetchmailrc`:

```
poll SERVER_ADDRESS with proto POP3 and options no dns
user 'MY_ADDRESS' there with password 'MY_PASSWORD' is 'MY_CURRENT_ACCOUNT_USERNAME' here options ssl
```

Then, I launched `Fetchmail`:

```
$> fetchmail -vk
```

And got a good answer:

```
fetchmail: POP3> LIST 1
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 1 6533
fetchmail: POP3> RETR 1
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 6533 octets
```

Trouble is, `Fetchmail` needs an MTA to finish fetching e-mails:

```
fetchmail: connection to localhost:smtp [127.0.0.1/25] failed: Connection refused.
fetchmail: SMTP connect to localhost failed
fetchmail: POP3> QUIT
```

So I installed `Postfix`. And configured it, and now, the process freezes after that:

```
Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1/25...connected.
```

Below is my `main.cf`:

```
myhostname = sultan
inet_protocols = all
biff = no
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
masquerade_exceptions = root
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains =
inet_interfaces = MY_IP 127.0.0.1 ::1
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
defer_transports =
mynetworks = MY_IP
disable_dns_lookups = no
relayhost =
content_filter =
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail
mailbox_transport =
strict_8bitmime = no
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
                            permit_mynetworks,
                            reject_invalid_hostname,
                            reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
                            reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                            reject_unauth_pipelining,
                            reject_unknown_client,
                            reject_unknown_hostname,
                            reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                          reject_unknown_client,
                          reject_invalid_hostname,
                          reject_unauth_pipelining,
                          reject_unknown_hostname,
```

Any idea?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much much easier to do this with [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) no need for a smtp-server etc.

*getmail is a mail retriever designed to allow you to get your mail from one or more mail accounts on various mail servers to your local machine for reading with a minimum of fuss. getmail is designed to be secure, flexible, reliable, and easy-to-use. getmail is designed to replace other mail retrievers such as fetchmail.*

http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/

Example getmailrc configuration:

```
[retriever]
type = SimplePOP3SSLRetriever
server = pop3.example.com
username = account_name
password = my_mail_password

[destination]
type = Maildir
path = ~/Maildir/
```

Comment: Perfect! Tack! ;)